# Module import fail

Tags: module, rust

I have simple code that imports 2 modules and uses struct from them. 
At *main.rs* I'm using functions from *bots/maintrait.rs* and *gamecore\board.rs* They both are imported same way, but func from *maintrait.rs* cannot be resolved.
Here is structure of my src directory:

```
.
├── bots
│   ├── maintrait.rs
│   └── mod.rs
├── gamecore
│   ├── board.rs
│   └── mod.rs
└── main.rs
```

And code:

*main.rs*

```
use gamecore::{GameBoard,State};
use bots::{Bot,DummyBot};

mod bots;
mod gamecore;

fn main() {
    let board = GameBoard::new();
    let bot = DummyBot::new(State::O);
    board.make_turn(State::X, (0, 0));
    board.make_turn(State::O, bot.get_move(&board));
}
```

*gamecore\mod.rs*

```
pub use self::board::{GameBoard,State};
mod board;
```

*gamecore\board.rs*

```
pub struct GameBoard {
    field: [[State, ..3], ..3]
}

impl GameBoard {
    pub fn new() -> GameBoard {
        GameBoard {
            field: [[State::Empty, ..3], ..3]
        }
    }
...
}
```

*bots\mod.rs*

```
pub use self::maintrait::{Bot,DummyBot};
mod maintrait;
```

*bots\maintrait.rs*

```
use gamecore::{GameBoard,State};
use std::rand;

pub trait Bot {
    fn new<'a>() -> Box<Bot + 'a>;
    fn get_move(&mut self, board: &GameBoard) -> (uint, uint);
}

pub struct DummyBot {
    side: State
}

impl Bot for DummyBot {
    fn new<'a>(side: State) -> Box<Bot + 'a> {
        box DummyBot{
            side: side
        }
    }

    fn get_move(&mut self, board: &GameBoard) -> (uint, uint) {
        let turn = rand::random::<uint>() % 9;
        (turn / 3, turn % 3)
    }   
}
```

*ERROR MESSAGE*

```
10:28 error: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared module `DummyBot`
let bot = DummyBot::new(State::O);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
10:28 error: unresolved name `DummyBot::new`
let bot = DummyBot::new(State::O);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Where I'm wrong? Why 2 same imports works diffirent?

Comment: I guess problem in implementation trait from `DummyBot` at submodule, but I dont know how to fix this without ruining code structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rust by Example](http://rustbyexample.com/trait.html) has a good example of how to do something similar.

Here's the appropriate bits of code that need to change:

```
pub trait Bot {
    // Your trait and implementation signatures differ, so I picked this one
    fn new() -> Self;
}

impl Bot for DummyBot {
    fn new() -> DummyBot {
        DummyBot{
            side: State::Empty
        }
    }
}

let bot: DummyBot = Bot::new();
```

I'm guessing a bit, but I think the underlying reason is that you haven't really defined a `DummyBot::new`, but instead have defined a generic `Bot::new` that `DummyBot` happens to implement. You have to call the defined method (`Bot::new`) *and* provide enough information to disambiguate the call (the type of the let).